# Node: npm install failure due to proxy config! What now?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, networking, proxy

I was trying to run node with the angular.js tutorial application and I found that npm isntall was not behaving itself.

I got a strange little spinning character that seemed to never stop.

I ran npm install -verbose and got the following debug trace:

```
216 error network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ETIMEDOUT
216 error network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
216 error network and is related to network connectivity.
216 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
216 error network
216 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
216 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

SO I've identified a problem. I've no idea how to go about fixing it. What do?

Comment: And you are behind a proxy?

Comment: I shouldn't be if I'm at home. Node seems to think otherwise

Answer (score 5):

Must configure the proxy you are using, in npm.

```
npm config set proxy http://<proxy-url>:<port>
npm config set https-proxy http://<proxy-url>:<port>
```

If you don't know proxy url, could get it by registry, in cmd run:

```
reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" | find /i "proxyserver"
```

Hope it helps, I faced the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem once and i solved it by :-

```
npm config set proxy


npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

Comment: If you are behind proxy, set the proxy in npm config file(C:\Users\{user_name}\.npmrc). See answer from @MarioAraya. Make sure that your proxy is not blocking npm registry url(cmd>ping registry.npmjs.org)

Comment: @rishabh-jain thanks that's really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing the same error of Proxy settings, first i found this was happening for default browsers settings problems.

```
npm config set rm proxy http.
npm config set rm https-proxy http.
```

Then Uninstall your Chrome browser and npm. Make default browser in Edge, then install npm and try the React-cli command.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

Then, simply install all the node modules by using `npm i` command