# Error when I use npm install with visual studio code

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-request

Hello I am working on a project where I have to build an API.
With node.js, express, and Mongodb.

When I install the dependencies of express or mongo db ( exemple :npm install express), I have a error.

I work with my wifi, yesterday everything was working though.
I don't understand why I have this problem now.
I must make configuration ?
I shared an image.

I work with visual studio code. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TBhz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is stated in the error description,
"there is a problem related to network connectivity".

Probably, it's the problem with your wifi connection.

Command "**npm install express**" should work just fine with normal connection.

Comment: I do not understand yet I am on a normal connection, wifi. Yesterday it worked very well, I connect from my home.

Comment: Do you use a proxy or vpn? Maybe some ports are closed?

Comment: I use my wifi (home), I installed node.js but the error contained.

Comment: You could try Rian's answer first to make sure it's not the proxy issue

Comment: Sorry I'm just starting out, but what is written at the top by Rian's ( thank you), I have to do it on a powershell or directly on Visual studio code in my folder "backend", because nothing is displayed?

Comment: You do it in the same terminal where you execute npm install

Answer (score 0):

check [Node: npm install failure due to proxy config! What now?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25826839/node-npm-install-failure-due-to-proxy-config-what-now)

and try

> npm config set proxy
>
> npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"

Comment: I must write this is line directly in the command line ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
The proxy you are using must be configured in npm.

```
npm config set proxy http://your url

npm config set https-proxy http://your url
```

If you don't know the proxy url, you can get it through the registry, run in cmd:

```
regquery "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" | find /i "proxyserver"
```